# clearstatcache() in GAE not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Unable to call google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageClient::clearStatCache()

GAE version 1.9.18.189, Mac OS

Comment: This is a known issue that should be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download and unpack zip package
2. Run dev_appserver.py

   ~google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check --port 8084 --admin_port 9004 --php_executable_path /usr/local/bin/php-cgi ~my_application

Comment: What makes this work is that you are switching out the runtime environment to one you control, i'm guessing. With the --php_executable_path